# Nodejs - TextWrap in cell while exporting data to excel

Tags: node.js, npm, exceljs

I am using exceljs npm package for formatting of excelsheet But I am not able to do textwrap inside cell when data is too large. My Description cell contains large data when excel is exported it looks like text is overlapping to next cell.

```
          try {
           var workbook = new excel.Workbook();
           var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('ABC');

           worksheet.columns = [
            { header: 'ABC', key: 'ABC', width: 15 },
            { header: 'Description', key: 'Description', width: 20 },
            { header: 'Comments', key: 'Comments', width: 20 }
        ];
        // setStyleToHeader(worksheet);
        worksheet.getRow(1).font = { name: 'Calibri', family: 4, size: 12, bold: true };
        worksheet.getRow(1).border = {
            top: { style: 'thin' },
            left: { style: 'thin' },
            bottom: { style: 'thin' },
            right: { style: 'thin' }
        };
        new sql.ConnectionPool(dbconfig).connect().then(pool => {
            return pool.request()
               .execute('sp_getAll_data')
        }).then(result => {
            debugger;
            let rows = result.recordset;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                worksheet.addRow({
                    ABC: rows[i].ABC,
                    Description: rows[i].Description ,
                    Comments: rows[i].Comments
                });
            }
            sql.close();
            workbook.xlsx.write(res);
            debugger;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats');
            res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "ABC.xlsx");
            res.end(result, 'binary');
            res.status(200).json();
        }).catch(err => {
            // res.status(500).send({ message: "${err}", err })
            // sql.close();
        });
    } catch (e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just wrap text you can use 'alignment' attribute of cell.

```
worksheet.getCell('D1').alignment = { wrapText: true };
```

It's alredy mentioned here in plugin page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#alignment